# Bootstrap no margin on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone i made a navigation in bootstrap, and first element is div class="navbar-header" then i added a little css to it because i wanted to be inline with elements below the navigation and everything is ok, work on all screens except one(Size: 768x1024, Tablet screen)
because it has a margin it pushes other elements below.

> .navbar-header {    margin-left:8% !important; }

i tried adding

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-header{
    margin-left:0;
    margin:0%;
    margin:0px;
}
```

but nothing happens, How do i replace margin-left on different screens? 
Thank you

Comment: try @media (min-width) and (max-width)

Answer (score 0):

you have place `!important` on your main rule. that's why your `media query` is not working.

in normal size use it without important;

```
.navbar-header { margin-left:8%; }
```

then in your media queries you can use other values ;

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header{
    margin-left:0;
}
```

**update:**

in that case you can define **2 media queries**. one for `>768` and one for `<768`. and put conflicting rules in these separate parts.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header{
    margin-left:8!important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-header{
    margin-left:0!important;
}
```

**sorry , I forgot to put % next to 8. below should work :**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header{
    margin-left:8%!important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-header{
    margin-left:0!important;
}
```

Comment: Sad and funny, works on tablet but on large screens margin isn't working